# Python 2D array search neighbors cell elements on row and column

Tags: python, arrays, replace, find, 2d

I have 2D array that depend on user input and each element only has 0 and 1. Example:
matric=[[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1] that represent virus infection, if user input in row[1,0,1] it will get infection on [1,0,1]=>[1,1,1] because the nearest cell to 1 will infect. I want to get all row and column from user input get infection if that value is 0 that next to or before the value 1.
Here my some code for infection cell:

```
def isInfected(grid, r, c):
    return grid[r][c] == 1
```

The function check get next infection:

```
def getNextInfectedCells(grid):
    row = len(grid)
    column = len(grid[0])
    result = []

    for r in range(row):
        result.append([])
        for c in range(column:
            if(r==0 or r==row-1) or (c==0 or c==column-1):
                result.append(grid[r][c])
            elif grid[r][c]==0:
                result[r].append(0)
            else:
                result[r].append(grid[r][c])
        for line in result:
            print(line)
```

What wrong! it not work
best regard!

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: you are trying to append a int value ( result[r] ) to a int value ( grid[r][c] ) in result[r].append(0) and result[r].append(grid[r][c]) both places.

Comment: for c in range(column:  is also wrong you forgot closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand a problem, but this code should work.

```
user_input = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1]]

for row in user_input:
    if 1 in row:
        infected = row.index(1) + 1
        row[infected] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it work but only row and I want it in row and column, for column it infect like row if column has value 1 it top and below column will infect as the same.

Comment: And the code above it work only value 0 between 1, ex:[1,0,1] but the process is all value in row that sit before and next to value 1 will be infect, Example: [1,0,0]=>will get [1,1,0] or [0,0,1]=>[0,1,1] for column the same if has value 1 thus the column top and below value 1 will infect, example: [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]=>[[1,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]